# Derivative of a function at a point

Tags: limits, derivatives

A friend who is still in highschool gave me the following problem. For $x>-1\,$ compute $f'(0)$  if $$f(x)=\left(x^2-\ln^2(x+1)\right)^\frac{1}{3}$$ Here is how I solved it. Since it just got messier if I computed the derivative then tried to plug in$x=0$ I used the definition of derivate: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(x^2-\ln^2(x+1)\right)^\frac{1}{3}-\left(0-0\right)^\frac{1}{3}}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(x^2-\ln^2(x+1)\right)^\frac{1}{3}}{x}.$$ We have the power series of $\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)\rightarrow\ln^2(1+x)=x^2-x^3+O(x^4)$ so the initial limit is just $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(x^3(1-O(x)\right)^\frac{1}{3}}{x}=1$$ I couldn't solve it with any other method and my friend didnt learn series yet. Could you help me with an elementary approach for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(x^2-\ln^2(x+1)\right)^\frac{1}{3}}{x}=l$$ 
Then by algebraic limit theorem
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(x^2-\ln^2(x+1)\right)}{x^3}=l^3$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(x-\ln(x+1)\right)}{x^2}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(x+\ln(x+1)\right)}{x}=l^3$$
Now using L'Hopital's rule on both parts
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(1-\frac1{(x+1)}\right)}{2x}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)}{1}=l^3 \\ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{2x(x+1)}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x+2}{x+1}=l^3 \\ l^3=1 \\l=1$$

Comment: How do you know that $l$ exists ?

Comment: TBH I don't. I was just hoping that it does. This isn't a good method for a proof. The method in the question is a lot better for proof. But this is a good method for someone in highschool who doesn't understand series expansion and stuff like that.

Comment: Shouldn't the reasoning be inverted? I.e.: After we calculated $l^3$, we can then conclude that indeed $$\lim_{x\to 0} \bigg(\frac{\left(x^2-\ln^2(x+1)\right)}{x}\bigg)^\frac{1}{3} = \bigg( \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(x^2-\ln^2(x+1)\right)}{x}\bigg)^\frac{1}{3}$$, as $x^\frac 1 3$ is continuous.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar  You can rearrange your answer without assuming that the limit exists (see my answer below). I'am ready to remove my answer if you do that.

Comment: @RobertZ I understand. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 5):

This is a rearranged version of Piyush Divyanakar's answer without the assumption that the given limit exists.

Note that by L'Hopital,
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x+\ln(x+1)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1+1/(x+1)}{1}=2$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\ln(x+1)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-1/(x+1)}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1/(x+1)^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Hence, as $x\to 0$,
$$\frac{\left(x^2-\ln^2(x+1)\right)^\frac{1}{3}}{x}=\left(\frac{x+\ln(x+1)}{x}\cdot \frac{x-\ln(x+1)}{x^2}\right)^{1/3}\to \left(2\cdot \frac{1}{2}\right)^{1/3}=1.$$
Hence
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{\left(x^2-\ln^2(x+1)\right)^\frac{1}{3}}{x}=1.$$

Comment: If you calculate $f'(x)$ then put $x= 0$ , it is undefined . Why ?

Comment: The definition of derivative at $0$ is $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$. Your $f'$ is defined for $x>0$.

Comment: @S.H.W Because $f$ is only one-sided differentiable. When $x\leq 0$ the part where $(a/x^3)^{1/3}=a^{1/3}/x$ is used is invalid.

Comment: @RobertZ I'm confused , the derivative function shows all of the points where the function is differentiable but here it doesn't work for zero .

Comment: @S.H.W Note that $f$ is a composition and one of the composed functions is $x\to x^{1/3}$ which is not differentiable at $0$. So for $x=0$, here we can't use the chain rule for the derivative.

Comment: @RobertZ I see , thanks a lot .